# How do defects in a superconducting nanostructure affect the supercurrent?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, nanoscience, topological-defects

I was wondering how point defects in a superconducting nanowire affect the supercurrent flowing through this wire.

In a naive view I am expecting the defect to decrease the maximum current allowed in the wire and also some changes to the streamlines of the current. When discussing this with some friends, somebody claimed that the supercurrent does not "see" defects smaller than the coherence length of the superconductor. I wanted to ask people with more in depth superconductivity knowledge if
a) is this true? and
b) if this is true: does the point defect matter at all or just in a reduced or smeared out way.

I am happy to hear any ideas from you, thanks.